# Holomorphic and antiholomorphic representation for $U(2)$ equivalent?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Consider the following two irreducible $U(2)$-representations:
$$V_1:=(\Bbb C^2)^*,\quad V_2:=\Bbb C^2,$$
where $U(2)$ acts as follows (with $v\in\Bbb C^2$):
$$(\rho_1(A)f)(v):=f(A^{-1}v),\quad \rho_2(A)v:=Av.$$
Let us describe the highest weights of $V_j$. Note that the complexified Lie algebra of $U(2)$ decomposes into
$$\mathfrak u(2)_\Bbb C=\Bbb C\operatorname{id}_2\oplus\ \mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C).$$
Thus, the roots of $\mathfrak{u}(2)_\Bbb C$ arise from the roots of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)$ by extending them by $0$ on the center $\Bbb C\operatorname{id}_2$. These are given by $\pm (e_1-e_2)$ with positive system $e_1-e_2$. The weights of $V_1$ resp. $V_2$ are given by $\{-e_1,-e_2\}$ resp. $\{e_1,e_2\}$ with highest weights $-e_2$ resp. $e_1$. However, we have $e_1+e_2=0$ so that the two weights coincide. By the theorem of the highest weight, $V_1$ and $V_2$ have to be isomorphic, but I do not think that they are. What am I missing? Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Maybe I'm unfamilar with notation, but I don't understand what $V_2$ is. Or rather, when you say $U(2)$ "acts by the left regular representation", then those two reps in my eyes are virtually the same because they let $U(2)$ act on a two-dimensional $\mathbb C$-vector space in exactly the same way (modulo choice of basis). If, on the other hand, the "antiholomorphic" $V_2$ is supposed to have an action of $U(2)$ precomposed with conjugation, as some of the notation suggests, then I don't think it's a complex representation at all (maybe a real one?). Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Its essentially the same as saying "$V_1$ is the contragredient of the standard representation and $V_2$ is the standard representation". So there is a complex conjugation preventing the two representations to be equivalent.

Comment: $V_2$ is equivalent to the standard representation of $U(2)$ on $\Bbb C^2$ by the equivariant isomorphism $\overline{z}_j\mapsto e_j$, where $e_j$ denotes the standard basis of $\Bbb C^2$. However, $V_1$ is not equivalent to the standard representation but rather to its dual.

Comment: Hmm, ok, if $V_2$ is just isomorphic to the standard left regular representation, then all that clutter seems just distracting for the question at hand, but maybe it's worthwhile for some general theory ... But then I ask, how does $V_1$ actually act, written down with matrices?

Comment: Because if it's via e.g. $\rho_1(\pmatrix{a&b\\-\bar b &\bar a} ). \pmatrix {z_1\\z_2} = \pmatrix{\bar a&\bar b\\-b&a} \pmatrix{z_1\\z_2}$, then this is just a manifestation of the fact that inverse-transpose on $SL_2$ is inner (https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Transpose-inverse_map_is_inner_automorphism_on_special_linear_group_of_degree_two), concretely here $\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}\pmatrix{a&b\\-\bar b &\bar a} \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0} =\pmatrix{\bar a&\bar b\\-b&a}$. (For unitary matrices, inverse-transpose = conjugate.)

Comment: The question arised in another context; I rewrote my question without the clutter now (didn't realize the isomorphism before, sorry for that). If I'm understanding your last comment right, you want to say that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are equivalent? I know that the dual of any irreducible $SU(2)$-representation is isomorphic to the representation. But is this the case for $U(2)$, too? In matrices the actions are given by:
$$\rho_1(\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}).v=\begin{pmatrix}\overline{a}&\overline{b}\\\overline{c}&\overline{d}\end{pmatrix}v$$ and $\rho_2(A).v=Av$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112670/discussion-between-nightgap-and-torsten-schoeneberg).

Comment: I just realised that the *roots*, which are $\pm(e_1-e_2)$, indeed *do* get extended by $0$ on the centre; but that just means that on the centre we have $e_1=e_2$ (which is not true on the $su$ part). As Qiaochu Yuan points out, conversely the condition $e_1+e_2=0$ is true only on the $su$ part, but not on the centre. So on the full group, the weights of the two reps do not coincide, although they would on $SU$, where as discussed the restricted reps indeed would be equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the defining representation $V = \mathbb{C}^2$ and its dual, and they are not isomorphic; you can very straightforwardly check that they have different characters by computing the trace of the action of a diagonal matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{array} \right], |a| = |b| = 1$, which in the defining representation is $a + b$ but which in the dual is $a^{-1} + b^{-1} = \overline{a + b}$.

<strike>The direct sum decomposition you write down is *not* a direct sum of Lie algebras, and</strike> your very last claim about weights is false; where weights of $U(2)$ are concerned it is just not true that $e_1 + e_2 = 0$. What is true is that if you restrict the action to $SU(2)$ then the two representations become isomorphic, because that's when it becomes true that $e_1 + e_2 = 0$. The weight lattice of $U(2)$ has rank $2$ because the maximal torus $T = U(1) \times U(1)$ (the diagonal matrices) has rank $2$.

Formally, on the Lie group level we have a short exact sequence

$$1 \to SU(2) \to U(2) \xrightarrow{\det} U(1) \to 1$$

which can be split by the map sending $z \in U(1)$ to the diagonal matrix $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} z & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$. This exhibits $U(2)$ as a nontrivial semidirect product

$$U(2) \cong SU(2) \rtimes U(1)$$

where the action of $SU(2)$ on $U(1)$ is given by conjugation by the diagonal matrix above. We have a corresponding nontrivial semidirect product decomposition

$$\mathfrak{u}(2) \cong \mathfrak{su}(2) \rtimes \mathfrak{u}(1).$$

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought one can and should decompose the Lie algebra into a *direct* product $\mathfrak{u}(n) \simeq \mathfrak{su}(n) \times \mathfrak z(\mathfrak u(n))$, the centre being one-(real-)dimensional. The problem is that this does almost but not quite lift to the group level because $SU(2) \cap Z(U(2)) = \pm Id$, accordingly a splitting of $det$ as $e^{ix} \mapsto \pmatrix{e^{ix/2}&0\\0&e^{ix/2}}$ does almost but not quite work. In a way the unitary group is just the wrong group to lift to, being neither simply-connected nor adjoint.

Comment: Hum, perhaps I spoke too hastily on the Lie algebra level; I suppose that's the Levi decomposition of $\mathfrak{u}(n)$? In any case the OP neglects the influence of the abelian factor when reasoning about weights.

Comment: One could call it a Levi decomposition, but it's just the splitting of a reductive Lie algebra into (semi)simple and centre. -- But yes, that's what we figured in the chat following the comments (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112670), it's the centre which makes all the difference here, and the roots are not just extended by $0$ on there. Unfortunately I don't have Knapp's text at hand to identify the mistake or misunderstanding. (But come to think of it, on the centre we have $e_1=e_2$, whereas indeed $e_1=-e_2$ holds only on the SU part.)

Comment: Youre absolutely right, thank you. @TorstenSchoeneberg there is no mistake in Knapps text: The roots (weights of the adjoint rep) are indeed extended by $0$ on the center. This makes sense since the adjoint rep acts trivially on the center and thus by 0 on the Lie algebra level. However, $e_1+e_2=0$ is only true for traceless matrices, i.e. for $\mathfrak{su}{2}$ but not for $\mathfrak{u}(2)$ (as you also pointed out) and the $e_j$ are not extended by $0$ on the center (it always picks the $j$-th diagonal entry). Thank you two for your help :)